# Cannot visit Public IP of gitlab-aws-image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gitlab

I followed https://about.gitlab.com/aws/ and I could not visit the "Public IP" of the aws image. It said "This site can’t be reached". So, then I ssh'd into the instance and found there was no /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file so I created one and simply pasted in the contents of https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template and replaced external_url 'GENERATED_EXTERNAL_URL' with the public IP. Still it doesn't work. Any tips?

Also on https://about.gitlab.com/aws/ it says you should use a c4.large instance but that sounds expensive -- can I just use a t2.micro?

I am used to using github so I was never worried about losing files but now that I'm hosting myself what is the professional way to backup (like what if the ec2 instance crashes) -- through s3 and by following http://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/backups.html?

Finally, The reason why I need to host my own gitlab is because I need to run pre-receive githooks. Is there any easier way to run pre-receive githooks without subscribing to an expensive enterprise service?

Comment: Did you launch the image?

Comment: @error2007s of course how else would i have been able to ssh in

Comment: i have a slight feeling like they omitted the fact that i have to go through http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/installation.html, i'm doing this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe https://about.gitlab.com/aws/ is broken. It's better to setup the default ubuntu instance given by amazon (you can pick t2.medium or c4.large) and then just follow the instructions for installation on gitlab.com for that version of ubuntu. It's just 4 steps (don't do the "from source").